# SSL Client Authenticated Webservice on ruby SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby, web-services, curl, ssl, authentication

I'm trying to connect to a webservice that requires SSL Client Authentication using ruby 2.1.2 but

When I use the same client certificate (client_cert.pem) on curl I've got the right response:

```
curl 'https://mywebservice.xxx.com' --cert client_cert.pem --cacert mycacert.crt
```

When I verbose curl I can see the handshaking going on like this:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.0.10...
* Connected to mywebservice.xxx.com (192.168.0.10) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*  ...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: mywebservice.xxx.com
> Accept: */*
> 
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Hello request (0):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 17 Jul 2014 12:50:26 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
< Pragma: No-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 21:00:00 BRT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
< 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> .....the full xml response
```

That's what I needed, but then I've tried the same on ruby:

```ruby
#ws_test.rb
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'openssl'

uri = URI.parse 'https://mywebservice.xxx.com/'
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
http.use_ssl = true
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("client_cert.pem"))
http.cert = cert
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

http.cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
cacert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("mycacert.crt"))
http.cert_store.add_cert(cacert)

http.start do
  http.request_get(uri.path) {|res|
    print res.body
  }
end
```

But on ruby I've got this problem:

```
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `block in connect'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
```

I've tried to change the verify_mode:

```
 http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER|OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT
 # same error
```

and

```
 http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
 # a different error: " SSL_read: ssl handshake failure (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using the gem rest_client...

This is what I did:

```
require 'rest_client'

RestClient::Resource.new(
  'https://mywebservice.xxx.com/',
  :ssl_client_cert  =>  OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("client_cert.crt")),
  :ssl_client_key   =>  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("client_cert.key")),
  :ssl_ca_file      =>  "mycacert.crt",
  :verify_ssl       =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
).get
```